# Make expandable flag options visible

Tags: feature-request, flags

I just started reviewing and made a mistake while flagging, because I didn't know that by clicking on a flag reason it can be expanded and show more flags. Could this be made more visible?

For instance, when you want to flag a post, you can hit Needs Improvement and then you can choose a further specification of the flag. However, you don't know beforehand that you have more options to choose from. That's why I once raised a moderator flag incorrectly.

A simple improvement would be to add some symbol that shows that the flag option is expandable, but maybe something more is better? (e.g. a different background color)

Comment: This also includes "A community specific reason" (which itself is a sub entry from "needs improvement") which also has a sub-dialog.